# Pimcore - get old Object state in preUpdateObject hook

Tags: php, content-management-system, zend-framework, pimcore

I need to compare if a certain property of my object has changed when someone is saving it. I wrote a plugin to be able to add some functionality before and after updating an object in the backend happens.

So, I don't know if this is not working as expected or if I'm getting this wrong.

I thought I would get the state before it is saved to the database in:

```
function preUpdateObject(Object_MyObject $object) {}
```

And the new state of the object in

```
function postUpdateObject(Object_MyObject $object) {}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
public function preUpdateObject(Object_MyObject $object) {
   $this->tempOldDate = $object->getUpdate();
}

public function postUpdateObject(Object_MyObject $object){
   if($this->tempOldDate->compareDate($object->getUpdate()) == -1) {
   // do something because a newer date has been entered   
   }
}
```

Any clue how I can get the old object state BEFORE it is updated??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this function is not working as expected. I filed a bug report:
http://www.pimcore.org/issues/browse/PIMCORE-1232

I created a workaround that can be used.

The database is NOT updated. So it's correct that preUpdateObject is the function to use to get the object state, but:

Check that database is not updated.... I want a date from my object that sits in table 'object_1'

```
// oldDate has the old value
$dbAdapter = Pimcore_Resource_Mysql::get("database");
$dbentry = $dbAdapter->fetchRow(
              $dbAdapter->select()
                        ->from('object_1')
                        ->where('o_id = ?', $object->getId()));     
$oldDate = new Pimcore_Date($dbentry['update']);
```

Using the generated Object class doesn't work, but if you clear the cache it does

```
// get's the new date from the editor 
$oldDate = Object_MyObject::getById($object->getId())->getUpdate();
// this also works but don't know if it is safe to delete
// the object from the registry
Zend_Registry::set('object_' . $object->getId(), false);
$oldDate = Object_MyObject::getById($object->getId())->getUpdate();
```